# camel: Modify output before routing

Tags: rest, apache-camel

In camel router I have below routing.

```
from("jetty:http://localhost:9092?matchOnUriPrefix=true").
    to("http://server:9093/service1?bridgeEndpoint=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=false")
    .to("http://server:9094/service2?bridgeEndpoint=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=false")
    .to("log:output")
```

The above routing works fine.

But my requirement is to modify the output of service1 before sending to service2. Like if I am getting 
    `<x>abc</x>`

I have to transform it to

```
<y><x>abc</x></y>
```

I tried using processor but I get the exchange.getOut() for service2 as null, while actually its returning the xml.

Can someone please help me if this is possible? Let me know if the question is not clear.

Comment: can you show your processor code.

Comment: Hi @user-soma,

Below is my processor code.

`.process(new Processor() {
   
   @Override
   public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    Message in = exchange.getOut();
    
    exchange.getOut().setBody(convertIncomingRequestToOutgoingRequest(in.getBody(IncomingRequest.class)));
   }`

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure where you are adding this processor in the route. The message into a processor is available on the in message on the exchange. I see that you are trying to pull the message from out.

When you set the body on an out message it is available on in message on the exchange at next endpoint or processor, so the right message on the exchange has to be picked up.

The below route should make sense, else paste your entire route along with the processor in your question and the members can see what the issue is:

```
from("jetty:http://localhost:9092?matchOnUriPrefix=true")
    .to("http://server:9093/service1?bridgeEndpoint=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=false").
        process(new Processor() {
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            String body = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
            exchange.getOut().setBody(modifyBody(body);
        }
        })
    .to("http://server:9094/service2?bridgeEndpoint=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=false")
    .to("log:output");
```

where modifyBody will be a custom method that will perform the required transformation.